# How to stop Sequelize converting a date extracted from the database in javascript framework

Tags: javascript, date, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize to extract a date from mssql database.

The SQL query I am sending through sequelize is:

```
SELECT TOP (1) createdAt FROM [dbo].[Tablename] where userID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' order by createdAt desc
```

In MSSQL management studio this returns a createdAt timestamp in the following format:

```
2020-07-15 16:27:09.2330000 +00:00
```

I just want to extract the date in that exact format.

However, when I extract this date using sequelize and write it to console log as shown below:

console.log("sqlResult[0].createdAt);

The date has been changed to this: Wed Jul 15 2020 17:08:26 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)

How do i just extract the date as the original string rather then being converted?

Comment: What does `sqlResult[0].createdAt.toISOString()` return?

Comment: Ah that does the trick thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem:

sqlResult[0].createdAt.toISOString()